# Как полностью вывести csv файл в консоль pyCharm?

Tags: python, pandas, консоль, csv

столкнулся с проблемой, что в консоли не хватает ширины вывода, то есть он выводит только 6 столбцов, а 7й переносит
[image]

команды
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pandas.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

не решают проблему, а делают только хуже

[image]

подскажите, может в настройках самого PyCharm есть какие-то параметры, которые можно изменить?
Использую PyCharm Professoinal

Comment: А сохранить таблицу в файл и смотреть там, не вариант?

Comment: В PyCharm в режиме отладки остановите программу в нужном месте и у каждого датафрейма, справа будет опция `view`.

Answer (score 4):

Добавьте еще опцию `pd.options.display.width = None`

```
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.width = None
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = None

df = pd.DataFrame([['Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа'] * 10] * 10)
print(df)
```

```
                                                                          0                                                                         1                                                                         2                                                                         3                                                                         4                                                                         5                                                                         6                                                                         7                                                                         8                                                                         9
0  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа
1  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа
2  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа
3  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа
4  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа
5  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа
6  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа
7  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа
8  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа
9  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа  Очень длинная строкааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа
```